Fill several polars columns with a constant value
I am working with the following code...
import polars as pl


df = pl.DataFrame({
    'region': ['GB', 'FR', 'US'],
    'qty':    [3, 6, -8],
    'price':  [100, 102, 95],
    'tenor':   ['1Y', '6M', '2Y'],
})

cols_to_set = ['price', 'tenor']
fill_val    = '-'

df.with_columns([pl.lit(fill_val).alias(c) for c in cols_to_set])

...with the following output.
shape: (3, 4)
┌────────┬─────┬───────┬───────┐
│ region ┆ qty ┆ price ┆ tenor │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str   │
╞════════╪═════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ GB     ┆ 3   ┆ -     ┆ -     │
│ FR     ┆ 6   ┆ -     ┆ -     │
│ US     ┆ -8  ┆ -     ┆ -     │
└────────┴─────┴───────┴───────┘

Instead of using a list of pl.lit expressions, I thought I could use a single pl.lit(fill_val).alias(cols_to_set). However, this crashes with an error
TypeError: argument 'name': 'list' object cannot be converted to 'PyString'

Is there a way to simplify the above and set all columns in cols_to_set to a specific constant value fill_val?

Super minor thing but with_columns takes *args so you can do df.with_columns(pl.lit(fill_val).alias(c) for c in cols_to_set), ie omit the brackets making it a generator instead of list comprehension but still works.

you could use replace_strict():
df.with_columns(pl.col(cols_to_set).replace_strict(None, None, default = '-'))

┌────────┬─────┬───────┬───────┐
│ region ┆ qty ┆ price ┆ tenor │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str   │
╞════════╪═════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ GB     ┆ 3   ┆ -     ┆ -     │
│ FR     ┆ 6   ┆ -     ┆ -     │
│ US     ┆ -8  ┆ -     ┆ -     │
└────────┴─────┴───────┴───────┘


Ah, beat me by seconds.

Tiny bit shorter would be to pass {} to replace_strict instead of None, None.

Your failing attempt has been previously requested[1]
You can use map() as an alernative to the list comp:
df.with_columns(map(pl.lit("-").alias, cols_to_set))

For a "single Polars expression" it is also possible with when/then + .fill_null()
df.with_columns(pl.when(False).then(pl.col(cols_to_set)).fill_null("-"))

shape: (3, 4)
┌────────┬─────┬───────┬───────┐
│ region ┆ qty ┆ price ┆ tenor │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str   │
╞════════╪═════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ GB     ┆ 3   ┆ -     ┆ -     │
│ FR     ┆ 6   ┆ -     ┆ -     │
│ US     ┆ -8  ┆ -     ┆ -     │
└────────┴─────┴───────┴───────┘


1. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12749
